# jQuery-UI datepicker shows only text

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I created a new ASP.net MVC Web Application project.  Inside my application, I created a controller called `Scheduler` with a view called `ApptsByDate`.

In the view, there is a textbox where I want the user to enter a date.  I tried using jQuery-UI datepicker for this and it is functional, but the datepicker displays only plain text.  I don't see any of the arrows or other icons that the user is supposed to be able to click on.

The ASP.net MVC 3 project is pre-populated with the following files:

```
/content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css
/content/themes/base/images/ui-bg_*
/content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_*
```

I can browse the icons in Visual Studio, but they never display in my page.  As the page renders in the browser, I can read the following from the page's `<head>` tag:

```
<script src='/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js"></script>

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/content/site.css' />
<link type="text/css" href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />     <!-- needed for jQuery-UI datepicker -->
```

Why am I not getting any decoration on my datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing the jquery ui css file. In general it comes with the jquery js file.

Comment: Actually, in the default project for ASP.net MVC 3, it is called `jquery.ui.all.css`, but your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are the css files in /Content/ or /content/? ...try changing the last line to this `<link type="text/css" href="/content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: I'm using IIS on the server-side, which I believe is not case-sensitive